# Potentiometer volume control for a piezo buzzer in bridge (2-pin) configuration

Tags: arduino, potentiometer, modulation, piezo, piezo-buzzer

I have a 10K potentiometer that I'd like to use to control the volume of a piezo transducer/buzzer, which is driven by one or more MCU PWM-capable pins (ranging from 0 to 3.3V). Originally, my configuration looked like this, using a single pin:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmWXHp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I need to adapt this to use a bridge configuration across the piezo buzzer, using two separate PWM-capable pins, similar to what's shown below, except with volume control somehow:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIZ4rE.png)</sup>

The bridge configuration has a number of advantages, like increasing the overall max volume and allowing emulation of two channels (similar to the [Arduboy2](https://github.com/MLXXXp/Arduboy2/blob/master/src/Arduboy2Beep.h) or [toneAC](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/ToneAC/) library).

Is there any simple way that I can effectively scale two separate signals with the same potentiometer? Preferably, I'd need to stick with simple through-hole components.

Some things I've thought about:

- Using diodes somehow, maybe in an ORing configuration, but I don't think this will give the desired effect.
- Since I do have a DAC available on my MCU (SAMD21E), I can mix the two audio signals (square waves) in firmware and output on the DAC pin, using the configuration in diagram 1 to control the overall volume.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: with only one speaker it's a single channel output, just use Spehro's circuit.  if you actually need to control two signals for some undisclosed reason use a dual potentiometer.

Comment: I get that it's only really one channel, but you're correct that I do need to toggle two signals to emulate two channels.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPaFGP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Just replace ground with the other phase.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This will give the volume advantage, but not the multi-channel emulation, unfortunately :(

Comment: I did update the question slightly with some info about ideas of my own.

Comment: If you can use the DAC that would be a good solution. Doesn't really lend itself to using PWM-based signals though.

Comment: Yeah that’s definitely a disadvantage. I could still do the mixing in an interrupt thankfully. Not quite as good as toggling the line directly but better than trying to achieve it in the main loop.

Comment: Or add a real mixer and bridged amplifier on the outputs but that's a bit more involved.

Comment: this will not harm the "multi channel", feature the piezo is isolated it doesn't respond to the "ground" voltage